# How to exec a function after previous ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

guys. It's a timer. I wanna run the timer and when it's end do something else(like a warning),and then run again with other amount of minutes. But I can't cause always only the second call is executed:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    timer(5,timer(25));

    // timer(5);
    // timer(25); do not work... only exec de last one
   
});

function timer(countTo,callback){

 var time = 10; /* how long the timer runs for */
 var initialOffset = '440';
 var i = 1
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
     $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/countTo)));
     $('h2').text(i);
     if (i == countTo) {
         clearInterval(interval);
     }
     i++;  
 }, 1000);
 callback();
}
```

Which is the best solution? There is something that I am not understanding... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timer(5,timer(25));
```

starts two timers and passes the result of the second (*undefined*) to the first as callback. You want:

```
timer(5,timer.bind(window,25));
```

And the callback needs to be executed if *i==countTo* ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off:

```
timer(5,timer(25));
```

If you think this line will execute `timer(5)`, and then at the end of `timer(5)` it will execute `timer(25)`, you are mistaken.  This is actually going to evaluate `timer(25)` immediately, and pass its return value (`undefined`) as the second parameter to `timer(5,undefined)`.

If you intended to pass that as a callback, you need to pass a function.  So you could do:

```
timer(5,timer.bind(null,25));
```

But, for that matter, you don't even check if `callback` exists before attempting to invoke it, so you probably are getting a reference error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
timer(5,function(){timer(25)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
timer(5,timer(25));
```

You should type

```
timer(5, function(){
  timer(25)
});
//or using ES6 syntax
timer(5, () => timer(25));
```

because `timer(25)` returns its value (this function doesn't return value so it tries to invoke undefined), not that function.
Also read about closures, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of runing a `callback()`, you need to run the function **itself** (`timer()`). You'll also need to run a `for` loop inside your function that checks how many times the function has already run. If it reaches your desired maximum, break out of that. This way it won't run indefinitely.

In the following example, the `timer()` function executes five times, which is what I'm assuming you want by calling `timer(5)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  timer(5);
});

function timer(countTo) {
  for (var iterations = 0; iterations < countTo; iterations++) {
    var time = 10; /* how long the timer runs for */
    var initialOffset = '440';
    var i = 1
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset - (i * (initialOffset / countTo)));
      $('h2').text(i);
      if (i == countTo) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

    }, 1000);
    timer();
    console.log("Iteration:", iterations + 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To run the function 25 times after this, all you have to do is call `timer(25)` directly after `timer(5)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  timer(5);
  timer(25);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  timer(5);
  timer(25);
});

function timer(countTo) {
  for (var iterations = 0; iterations < countTo; iterations++) {
    var time = 10; /* how long the timer runs for */
    var initialOffset = '440';
    var i = 1
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset - (i * (initialOffset / countTo)));
      $('h2').text(i);
      if (i == countTo) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

    }, 1000);
    timer();
    console.log("Iteration:", iterations + 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use it!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear this solution appears to have helped you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)

Comment: This will recursively start Intervals, which just works because timer() causes countTo to be undefined so the for loop will never run. If you do sth like timer(5) it will crash => so no, this is not an answer